# Axis date format for a surface plot in Plotly

Tags: plotly

My date format for my axis labels works fine if the chart type is heatmap or contour, but when I make a surface plot, my date format is not taken, and a default format is used instead. I want the date format to show the month and day, leaving out the year. This is because the year goes on the y-axis, while the calendar day goes on the x-axis. I am using the year 2000 as a template for the x-axis dates, but I don't want the labels to say 2000.  My workaround, for now, is to show the calendar date as a value from 0-365, but that makes the chart harder to understand.

How I formatted my labels:

```
2007   +      +      +      +
2008   +      +      +      +
2009   +      +      +      +
2010   +      +      +      +
     Jan-1  Apr-1  Jul-1  Oct-1
```

How Plotly formats my labels in spite of my instructions

```
2007     +      +         +         +
2008     +      +         +         +
2009     +      +         +         +
2010     +      +         +         +
     Jan 2000  Apr 2000  Jul 2000  Oct 2000
```

My ugly workaround:

```
2007  +  +  +   +
2008  +  +  +   +
2009  +  +  +   +
2010  +  +  +   +
      0  91 182 274
```

Some relevant links:

- https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/surface/
- https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-tickformat

Is there any way to get the dates formatted on the x-axis for a surface plot?